# How to find value in json

Tags: javascript, json

How to fine state name using postcode in bellow  json data;

```
var data = '{
  "1": {
    "state": "VIC",
    "postcode": "2600,2603,2605,2606"
  },
  "2": {
    "state": "NSW",
    "postcode": "2259,2264"
  }
}'
```

How to find `state` by `postcode`;

if i search postcode `2600` if get result like `VIC`

Comment: first, you want to JSON.parse(data) (though, that wont work as is, because what you've posted is not valid javascript) - then it's just a regular object you'll be dealing with

Comment: `if i search postcode` - how are you "searching" ... show some code

Comment: passing postcode value in some function and function return state name

Comment: no matter what you do with this data, it will be wrong ... postcodes in the range 2600->2639 are not **VIC**

Comment: I assume from the Javascript tag that you want to parse it in Javascript, but if you just need to extract values from a file containing JSON data, your best bet is `jq`: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/iwek/3924925 worked for me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Remove `''` as yours is not a valid string, remove `''` to make it a valid object literal, then you can iterate over the keys of the Object and check if it has the matching POSTCODE and if it has then return it's corresponding state.

```js
var data = {
  "1": {
    "state": "VIC",
    "postcode": "2600,2603,2605,2606"
  },
  "2": {
    "state": "NSW",
    "postcode": "2259,2264"
  }
};

function getState(data, postcode){

  for(var x in data){
    if(data[x].postcode && data[x].postcode.split(",").indexOf(postcode.toString())!=-1) return data[x].state;
  }
  
  return "Not Found";
  
}

alert(getState(data, "2600"));
alert(getState(data, 2264));
```

You can directly do `.indexOf` on the postcode, even without using `.split(",")`. But, then, it will also match with ,`2600` which should not be the case. So, use `split`.

Use `json[x].postcode` condition to make sure that postcode field exists in the object. Otherwise, it will give an error if it does not exist.

Comment: If you remove the `''` from data it is no longer JSON, it's an object literal

Comment: @RGraham it was no JSON it was Syntax Error

Comment: @RGraham it is a syntax error in OP code.

Comment: @CodeiSir Correct. What OP had was a JSON string, albeit not correctly constructed, but this is not **JSON** either. Not saying this is wrong, just incorrect terminology.

Comment: @CodeiSir SIR, yours i valid JSON string :)

Comment: `Remove '' from the data variable ot make it a valid JSON, then you can parse the JSON` - no no no no no ... removing the `' '` will make it a regular object literal ... then there's no JSON to parse

Comment: @JaromandaX That's what I was trying to say, but I think you put it much clearer than me :)

Comment: It also wont work if you try to find `2600`, wich is not a string

Comment: because you weren't first :p - I didn't downvote you, but if you change 'VIC' to 'ACT' I'll upvote you because you've corrected a grievous error in the data :p

Comment: well i did not downvote, but it's missing the JSON and the postcode of type number

Comment: @CodeiSir yeah that too works now.

Comment: @JaromandaX ??? LOL.

Comment: you make x variable global, you need to add `var`

Comment: @jcubic yeah, missed that. Done.

Comment: also please don't call the var `json` when it's not JSON. Otherwise our friends might never learn the diffrence

Comment: @CodeiSir yep, thanks for refining it to such an extent.

Comment: well I have some more suggestion but its details. JSON however gets confused all the time with Objects, so I think we should not support that confusion

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 7):

Try like this

```
var data = '{"1": { "state": "VIC","postcode": "2600,2603,2605,2606"}, "2": {"state": "NSW","postcode": "2259,2264"}}';
var jsObj = JSON.parse(data);
var find = "2600";

var values = Object.keys(jsObj).filter(function(x) {
  return jsObj[x].postcode.indexOf(find) > -1;
}).map(function(x) {
  return jsObj[x].state;
});

console.log(values.length > 0 ? values[0] : "not found");
```

<kbd>**[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/pw1u4pum/)**</kbd>

Comment: neither is yours, @CodeiSir - consider real world data of 10's of thousands of postcodes ... none of the answers posted will perform very well

Comment: @JaromandaX how would you make "mine" faster? (wich is pretty much the same as the accepted answer, appart from the `.toString()` that is called way to often :P

Comment: I couldn't make yours or anyone else's faster - I'd write it in a different way - you brought up performance, I was simply pointing out performance for this simple example is negligible amongst all answers

Answer (score 5):

```js
function findState(data, postcode) {
  var postcode = postcode.toString()
  for (var k in data) {
    var postcodes = data[k].postcode.split(",")
    if (postcodes.indexOf(postcode) != -1)
      return data[k].state
  }
}

// Demo Output
var data = '{"1":{"state":"VIC","postcode":"2600,2603,2605,2606"},"2":{"state":"NSW","postcode":"2259,2264"}}'
var dataObj = JSON.parse(data)

var state = findState(dataObj, 2600)
document.write(state)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```js
function searchInObject(object, searchKey, searchValue) {
  for (var i in object) {
    if (object[i][searchKey].indexOf(searchValue) > -1) {
      return object[i];
    }
  }
}

(function() {
  var data = {
    "1": {
      "state": "VIC",
      "postcode": "2600,2603,2605,2606"
    },
    "2": {
      "state": "NSW",
      "postcode": "2259,2264"
    }
  }

  var pin = "2600";
  var result = searchInObject(data, "postcode", pin);
  console.log(result.state);

  pin = "2259";
  result = searchInObject(data, "postcode", pin);
  console.log(result.state);
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well now.. You are just asking us to help you with homework :) Good thing im in a good mood.

First get a proper JSON string, and parse it into a object using `JSON.parse`. Then iterate this object and split the postcode string and find the state!

```
var data = ......
var resp = JSON.parse(data);

function getStateByPostcode(postcode) {
  var state = "";
  for(var i in resp) {
    if(resp.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
       var postcodes = resp[i]['postcode'].split(',');
       if(postcodes.indexOf(postcode) !== -1) {
           return resp[i]['state'];
       }
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```